# On ng-blur, i'm updating the model bound to the input, but the input reassumes focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with angular updating the focus of my interface when a bound variable changes. I've got an array of author objects, and am using an ngRepeat to display their names in inputs.  On blur of the input I make an httpRequest to validate the name, and if it is correct I update the entire author object from the DB.

The blur is working correctly and so is the httpRequest, but when the data returns and I assign it back to the model the input for that author is reassuming focus.

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="author in authors" ng-blur="validateName($index)" ng-model="author.name" />

$scope.validateName = function(index) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET'',
        url: 'someUrl',
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Authorization": bearer
        }
    })
    .then(function(r) {
        $scope.authors[index] = r.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I've just tested this without an $http call and it works fine. It must be something associated with the API call or the returned data that is causing the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reassuming' focus?

Comment: I mean the focus is placed back on the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in callback try this

```
angular.merge($scope.authors[index], r.data);
```

probably angular loses reference when assign new object